# php code to make live html canvas for two clients on the internet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

I need html, PHP, Jquery code to make live html canvas (Like white board) for two online users so that if one of them update on canvas then another one can see it in live. Is there any idea for implementing this canvas. In need code for this purpose in php. **I found one code sample on  internet which i linked [here](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example5.html)**

I need this code such that two users can interact using drawing or writing over html canvas.

**Following is the snapshot of the example**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you some starting information:

**Websockets** is a method to allow distributed computers to communicate through a common server.

A library like Ratchet handles the websockets for you on a PHP server:

http://socketo.me/docs.

To effectively combine drawing efforts on canvas from multiple users, you must capture each of the latest drawing commands from each user and distribute those latest commands to all the other users.  Here's an example of how to serialize canvas drawing commands:

http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/deserializing-recordings-in-recordable-html5-canvas/

A full answer (requiring server configuration) is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

To implement a live canvas paradigm, your going to have to take advantage of WebRTC. WebRTC is a free, open project that enables web browsers with Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via simple JavaScript APIs.

I suggest checking out the article [Getting Started wih WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

For official information, check out [WebRTC.org](http://www.webrtc.org/)

-happy learning!

Comment: I think it is for video communication, but i need to provide communication through canvas. still thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: WebRTC is most known at the moment for video chat. But, WebRTC can have multiple purposes as it's main goal is to provide real time communication among peers in a cloud network. What you want, is to display real time events from canvas onto another web browser in real time. Web RTC can offer this -it just hasn't been built yet. You can be he first to implement this wonderful idea!